# Enter data to MySQL Xcode post method

Tags: mysql, ios, post

I have seen examples where they explain this:

File: file.php (not shown)

File xcode (.m - method IBAction)

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/file.php?name=%@",inputName.text];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

But now I need to get data sent by the POST method.
Why? There are about 60 fields to enter too.

So you only need to refer to the file (file.php) to enter all?